# How to make optional field base on other field in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to make optional field in Mongoose schema.

Here is my `Log` schema.

```
var logSchema = new Schema({
    logType: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['user', 'lead', 'knowledgecenter'],
        required: true
    },
    userLog: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        userId: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true
        }
    },
    leadLog: {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        leadId: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

I want to insert document in above `Log` schema either with `{logType:'user',userLog:{userId:'5fcJFjslkka4lsdk'}}` or `{logType:'lead',leadLog:{leadId:'5fcJFjslkka4lsdk'}}`.

But at this moment mongoose throw  `ValidatorError: Path required` error.

Comment: All fields in mongoose are optional by default except the `id` field!

Comment: but here i set `required` option for each field. So, they are not optional now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of setting `required` to `true` you can set it to be a function that returns true only in the case where it is required.

this should do the trick:

```
var logSchema = new Schema({
    logType: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['user', 'lead', 'knowledgecenter'],
        required: true
    },
    userLog: {
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: function() { return this.logType === 'user'; }
        },
        userId: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          required: function() { return this.logType === 'user'; }
        }
    },
    leadLog: {
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: function() { return this.logType === 'lead'; }
      },
      leadId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: function() { return this.logType === 'lead'; }
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks @Josh, can you please suggest me any other design of above schema which will be better.

Comment: @vineetsah, I havn't used mongoose in a while, I just remembered dealing with this specific headache. That said, your schema looks good to me.